# Can't install tmux. Error: dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib

Tags: macos, tmux

I tried installing tmux by doing the steps specified [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/127186/installing-tmux-but-getting-dyld-library-not-loaded-referenced-from-usr). I have tried all the suggested steps, but the terminal still gave me this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/libevent/lib/libevent-2.1.6.dylib
Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Answer (score 30):

Reinstalling openssl did not work for me, but

```
brew upgrade tmux
```

got me to version 3.0a and got rid of the error.

Comment: I encountered this issue when I changed my ruby version (via rbenv), but the events might not be related at all, however updating tmux worked for me as well.

Comment: I had success w a variant of this approach: a bunch of cycles of brew update && brew upgrade, discovering & fixing dependency breaks along the way.

Comment: @SammanBikramThapa I also had this problem when I switched from rvm to rbenv. that makes me think the events are related. wonder why!

Answer (score 6):

These steps are worked for me.

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies openssl
brew install openssl
```

Comment: Works for me, too.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you don't have `openssl` lib. Try to install with `brew install openssl`

Answer (score 1):

I tried the answer by @Kaifei, but ran into problems with **`openssh`**. At the end, I also had to do:

```
brew upgrade openssh
```

to resolve the issue. [This blog](https://blog.junjizhi.com/all/2019/12/17/git-fetch-libssl-error.html) talks about this solution.